# Why is my entire 'grid-column: 3' showing up as a button?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Below is the code I am using. I cannot, after re-evaluating the code for upwards of an hour, figure out why the entire 3rd column in my grid display is not displaying properly.

I have searched for 'cursor: pointer' code where it shouldn't be, and I have attempted to reverse engineer it using background colors to find placement issues. Can anyone shed some light or take a stab at why this isn't working? Grateful for any and all feedback!

```css
/* Fund Library Section */
.fund {
  background: #000000;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.fund__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.fund__container h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  justify-self: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.row_user {
  grid-column: 1;
  justify-self: center;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: #fff;
}

.label_title {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 12px 6px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 18px 12px 6px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.textbox {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="number"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 55%;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4287f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row_button {
  background: #fff;
  grid-column: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}

.main_btn {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  background: #1e3c72;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}

.main_btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fd1d1d;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main_btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.main_btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.row_fund-frame {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 3;
  justify-self: center;
}

.static_labels {
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Fund Library Section -->
<div class="fund" id="home">
  <div class="fund__container">
    <h1>Fund Library</h1>
    <div class="row_user">
      <div class="label_title">
        <label for="fundticker">Fund Ticker</label>
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="fundticker"
          name="fundticker"
          placeholder="Example: AGTHX"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        <label for="short-low">Short Term Capital Gain (Low) %</label>
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        <input
          type="number"
          id="short-low"
          name="short-low"
          placeholder="Enter %..."
        />
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        <label for="short-high">Short Term Capital Gain (High) %</label>
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        <input
          type="number"
          id="short-high"
          name="short-high"
          placeholder="Enter %..."
        />
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        <label for="long-low">Long Term Capital Gain (Low) %</label>
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        <input
          type="number"
          id="long-low"
          name="long-low"
          placeholder="Enter %..."
        />
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        <label for="long-high">Long Term Capital Gain (High) %</label>
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        <input
          type="number"
          id="long-high"
          name="long-high"
          placeholder="Enter %..."
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_button">
      <button class="main_btn"><a href="#">Submit Fund</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row_fund-frame">
      <ol class="static_labels">
        <li class="static_fund">Fund Name</li>
        <li class="static_fund">Fund Ticker</li>
        <li class="static_fund">Short Capital Gains %s</li>
        <li class="static_fund">Long Capital Gains %s</li>
      </ol>
      <ol class="dynamic_labels">
        <li class="dynamic_fund">DB Fund Name</li>
        <li class="dynamic_fund">DB Fund Ticker</li>
        <li class="dynamic_fund">DB Short Capital Gains %s</li>
        <li class="dynamic_fund">DB Long Capital Gains %s</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my answear that you can see that is works.

Comment: You cannot have `a` inside `button` (or vice versa).

Comment: @connexo thank you guys so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Correct the error in your markup

As @connexo pointed out in the comments, you've got an Anchor tag, inside of a button tag. More importantly, you never close the A tag, so the button tag continues to wrap the remainder of the third column. Here's the offending line:

```
<button class="main_btn"><a href="#">Submit Fund</button>
```

And it should be either a button, OR an anchor, not both.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution helped a lot. Can I ask, I believe the main reason the <anchor> tag was useful was because of the 'slide' animation you get when hovering over the button itself. When I remove the <anchor> tags, the animation does not work properly. Would there be a way to re-position that animation so that an <anchor> tag isn't required? Let me know if this question makes sense. Thanks again :)